# find min value according to index of values

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
d <- data.frame(date = c('1976-04-27','1976-04-27','1976-04-27',
                         '1976-04-28','1976-04-28','1976-04-28'),
                height = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,3),
                val = c(1,5,8,7,4,6))

> d
        date height val
1 1976-04-27    0.1   1
2 1976-04-27    0.2   5
3 1976-04-27    0.3   8
4 1976-04-28    1.0   7
5 1976-04-28    2.0   4
6 1976-04-28    3.0   6
```

for each unique 'date' I would like to find the 'val' that corresponds to the min 'height'. Thus, the answer I eventually want is 1 and 7. I can acheive the desired result with a loop as:

```
tt <- sapply(as.Date(d[,1]), unique)
uniq_tt <- unique(tt)
a <- NA
for (i in 1:length(uniq_tt)){
  indx <- tt == uniq_tt[i]
  d2 <- d[indx,]
  a[i] <- d2[which.min(d2[,2]),3]
}

> a
[1] 1 7
```

but was hoping that there was a way of doing this without the loop. My actual data is much larger than this so will take a long time if I have to keep the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this in a number of group by ways.  One option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`), grouped by 'date', we find the index of 'min' value of 'height' and use that to filter the corresponding 'val' rows.  Extract the output column (`$V1`) to get the vector of 'val'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, val[which.min(height)], by = date]$V1
#[1] 1 7
```

---

Or use `dplyr` with the same methodology.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(Val= val[which.min(height)]) %>%
  .$Val
```

---

Or a `base R` approach with `ave`

```
d$val[as.logical(with(d, ave(height, date, 
           FUN= function(x) x==min(x))))]
#[1] 1 7
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in base R using `sapply`. First split the data frame by `date` using `split` and then use `which.min` to find the minimum in each list.

```
sapply(split(d, d$date), function(d) d[which.min(d$height), 3])

# 1976-04-27 1976-04-28 
#         1          7
```